# runtime SWF loading with haxe

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'm looking at http://github.com/openfl/swf and it looks like it requires the assets to be embedded/compiled into the resulting file.

Is there any way to load an swf run-time, and have the application interact with any supplied swf?

It looks like the neko target allows the swf to be loaded run time from the assets sub folder, however the flash target compiles the external swf into the generated swf(based on the fact that I can see the classes inside the generated swf).